# Vertica GET_COMPLIANCE_STATUS() discrepancy

Tags: vertica, vsql

We use Vertica Community Edition which allows us to store data up to 1 TB. Vertica is hosted on-premise and we have allocated 153 GB for it to use, out of which 57 GB (39%) is used so far.

[image]

When I run `SELECT GET_COMPLIANCE_STATUS()`, it shows I have used 0.91 TB (91%) of the allowed disk space. I have executed `SELECT AUDIT_LICENSE_SIZE()` to make sure we get the latest compliance data.

[image]

I am wondering why these numbers do not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disk usage is the compressed/encoded ROS files.

For license calculation Vertica uses uncompressed files to sum over the total size. 1 TB for community edition is uncompressed size of the files.

Disk usage can vary depending upon how many projections you create.

Note: Additional Projections does not count to the license size. Only additional Tables and External tables do.

Answer (score 1):

As @minatverma says - the audit size is the uncompressed size of the data.

It's actually the answer to the question of how many terabytes the export files would occupy if you exported all data tables to CSV files, not counting the delimiters and counting 0 bytes for NULL values.

This has only a very theoretical correlation with the size of the ROS files on disk. Vertica is a columnar database. Each column , roughly , is one file.

So, if you have, for example, a `gender` column that can only assume 'M' or 'F', have the projection ordered by this column first, and the column encoded as Run-Length-Encoding (RLE), this file will not occupy more than some twenty bytes - whether the table has 100 or 1 million rows: The value 'F', followed by the integer 500002 (the value occurs so many times), and the value 'M', followed by the integer 499998.

So, you see, they have little to do with each other: in the CSV file, you have one million times 1 byte for that.